# Substituir palavras em no site

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

Eu uso o código abaixo para gerar um espaço com os comentários recentes feitos no meu blog. Está funcionando perfeitamente, só que o Disqus gera a data do comentário em inglês. Ex: 1 month ago, 2 weeks ago, 1 day ago. Gostaria que alguém me ajudasse com um trecho que substitua "month ago" por "mês atrás" por exemplo.

obs.: Não sei se é possível deixar o link para meu blog aqui então não deixei

```css
.dsq-widget ul.dsq-widget-list{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    text-align:left
}

img.dsq-widget-avatar{
    margin:6px 10px 7px 0!important;
    width:60px!important;
    height:60px!important;
    padding:0!important;
    float:left;
    border-radius:3px!important
}

p.dsq-widget-meta{
    clear:both;
    font-size:80%;
    margin-top:5px!important
}

p.dsq-widget-meta a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:48%;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    -webkit-text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap
}

li.dsq-widget-item{
    margin:0!important;
    padding:6px 0 4px!important;
    list-style-type:none;
    clear:both;
    border-bottom:1px solid #EBEBEB
}

li.dsq-widget-item:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEB
}

a.dsq-widget-user{
    font-weight:700;
    display:block!important;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px
}

.dsq-widget-comment p{text-transform:lowercase;color:#888;font-size:12px}
```

```html
<div id="RecentComments" class="dsq-widget">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vida-xbox.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=5&hide_mods=0&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=32&excerpt_length=70"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: E isso não te ajuda: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466249-multi-lingual-websites?

Comment: Não, já tentei isso antes mas não funcionou. Se ajuda eu realmente não sei como usar

Comment: Weslley, esse código que você disponibilizou não serve de nada para sua pergunta.

Comment: Esse código gera a área com os comentários recentes e as informações da data (em inglês). Quero saber como substituir o texto em inglês por um que eu quero em português. O trecho em CSS lida com a parte do visual

Comment: O ideal mesmo seria ver o que o código Javascript tráz pro front através desse RecentComents